# Cannot see keyframes for objects

Tags: animation, camera, keyframes

I'm pretty new in Blender when it comes to the features, so I hope this is just a button I accidentally clicked.
I was animating as per usual, but then the keyframes for my non-greasepencil objects disappeared, they still move around as if the keyframes were still there. I can make new keyframes for the objects, but I can't see them either. I can see the keyframes for my greasepencil objects.[image].[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but deleting the old dope sheet and making a new one fixed it.